# Disable order checkout for email if order already exists with billing_email

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a single product and would like to disable checkout if the 'billing_email' entered on the checkout form already exists within the orders db.

This is what I have:

```html
<?php if(is_page( 'checkout' )): ?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=billing_email]').change(function() {
        var input_value = $(this).val();
        $.post(
            validateEmail.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'validate_email',
            billing_email: input_value
        }, function(data) {
            $('.message').html(data);
            if (data == 'existed') {
                document.getElementById('place_order').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
         } else {
                    document.getElementById('place_order').removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How would I go about checking the existing orders for a matching email?

Comment: You could use [`wc_get_orders`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) 
and then apply a count to the result, if > 0... 
it just doesn't seem user-friendly to me to prevent further ordering during the checkout process when entering an email address. 
It seems better that customers have to enter their email address before they can add products to the shopping cart and since this check has already taken place

Comment: ...well, you probably need to do both.